# Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

Android Studio gives error when running application with instant run enabled. I have updated my android studio to 2.3 today and since then its showing me above information.

Comment: did you perform a clean, validate and restart
?

Answer (score 1):

On android studio 3.0.1 
I ran a full build right after I enabled instant run. 
Once that was done . The error was gone and instant run worked.

Answer (score 0):

Re-run **Android studio** with **emulator** helped me to install it on next lunch.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using external devices then turn On or Off the device, or connection miss-match. please retry to connect devices and run your application then reconnect device.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable Instant Run by going to  (in android studio) *File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run*

and **uncheck Instant Run**

Comment: why would I want to do that ?

Comment: The error come because Intant run dont install in the device the app correctly due his optimization. It dissable the Instant run and the error disappears. Is not the best solution, but work